# Github not rendering python notebook

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook

When I upload my python notebook to github. The github is not able to render the python notebook properly and displaying the notebook horizontally as opposed to vertically. Can anyone please help me out with this?

[Github render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFlFp.jpg)

Comment: Can you share the github url for this notebook?

Comment: The URL is https://github.com/SATHVIKRAJU/Inferential_Statistics/blob/master/Human_Temp.ipynb

Comment: I see you resolved this by breaking your file into divs.

Comment: Yes.. I resolved this by breaking into divs.

Comment: If you are allowed to then post the answer here.